# difference between Query and Model mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-models, mongoose-q

these days i'm trying to learn more about mongoose to implement it in my project ,while going through the doc , i saw both [Model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Model) and [Query](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Query), both have many methods in common ,my question is what is the difference between them for example

`Model.findOne()`vs `Query.prototype.findOne()`, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Model.findOne()** is the actual way to finding single document from database using findOne() query

whereas **Query.prototype.findOne()** means prototype of findOne Query

[as per documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOne) : you can pass your **filter, projection, options** objects and **callback** function to your query

example :

```
 Kitten.where({ color: 'white' }).findOne(function (err, kitten) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      if (kitten) {
        // doc may be null if no document matched
      }
 });
```

mongoose have displayed prototypes of all [Query](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Query) you can use to your Model , means what you can pass to your Query while finding documents.

Comment: i guess `prototype` is related to inheritance, and not what you meant here.
[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)