# difference between Model.find and Query.prototype.find()

Tags: javascript, mongoose

What is the difference between [Model.find()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.find()) and [Query.prototype.find()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#Query.prototype.find()) in [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/)? They both seem to do the same thing, return a [Query](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#Query()) instance. Is there any difference between them at all? Should I use one vs the other? My apologies if questions seem too simple. I'm not new to programming but new to JavaScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [difference between Query and Model mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53437031/difference-between-query-and-model-mongoose)

Answer (score 1):

From the [queries](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) documentation, we know:

> Mongoose models provide several static helper functions for CRUD operations. Each of these functions returns a mongoose `Query` object.

`Model.find()` method is just a wrapper for `Query.prototype.find()` method. These methods like [`Model.deleteOne()`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/7.1.1/lib/model.js#L1968),
`Model.find()` that are often used on the Model encapsulate several method calls on the query object, which is more convenient to use

`Model.find()` source code, see [7.1.1/lib/model.js#L2045](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/7.1.1/lib/model.js#L2045)

```js
Model.find = function find(conditions, projection, options) {
  _checkContext(this, 'find');
  if (typeof arguments[0] === 'function' || typeof arguments[1] === 'function' || typeof arguments[2] === 'function' || typeof arguments[3] === 'function') {
    throw new MongooseError('Model.find() no longer accepts a callback');
  }

  const mq = new this.Query({}, {}, this, this.$__collection);
  mq.select(projection);
  mq.setOptions(options);

  return mq.find(conditions);
};
```

`this.Query` is the subclass of the `Query` class, see [7.1.1/lib/model.js#L4620](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/7.1.1/lib/model.js#L4620)

```js
const Query = require('./query');
// ...

model.Query = function() {
  Query.apply(this, arguments);
};
Object.setPrototypeOf(model.Query.prototype, Query.prototype);
```

How does the inheritance work? See [Pseudoclassical inheritance using Object.setPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf#pseudoclassical_inheritance_using_object.setprototypeof)

It creates a query instance and calls [Query.prototype.select()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#Query.prototype.select()) and [Query.prototype.setOptions()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#Query.prototype.setOptions()) to set the `projection` and `options` for query. In the end, call [Query.prototype.find()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#Query.prototype.find()) method.

Comment: "*`this.Query` is the `Query` class*" - actually it's a subclass of `Query`